# How to create a composite primary key using SQLite Manager

Tags: sqlite, primary-key, composite-primary-key, sqlitemanager

For a project I'm working on one of my SQLite tables requires a composite primary key consisting of two foreign keys. The record retrieval relies on two conditions; a college course and the students that are enrolled onto that course.

I cant see anywhere in SQLite manager that will allow me to create a composite key for this table. Maybe i'm just not seeing it, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check "primary key" for both columns.